# Trying to prevent session tampering works on local environment but not on prod server

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, global-asax

So i want to prevent session tampering in my site and i implemented this in global.asax. What im doing is im generating a hash key using the GenerateHashKey function. which basically uses the browser version,userhost address etc to create a hash key. This hash key im attaching to ASP.NET_SessionId cookie. Now this works perfectly in local environment. but as soon as i host it to prod server, the "Invalid" exception is thrown the first time and then it works fine. why is this happening

I used this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/859579/Hack-proof-your-asp-net-applications-from-Session

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null && Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value != null)
            {
                string newSessionID = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value;
                //Check the valid length of your Generated Session ID
                if (newSessionID.Length <= 24)
                {
                    //Log the attack details here

                    Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
                    Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = null;
                    throw new HttpException("Empty");

                }

                //Genrate Hash key for this User,Browser and machine and match with the Entered NewSessionID
                if (GenerateHashKey() != newSessionID.Substring(24))
                {
                    //Log the attack details here
                    Response.Cookies["TriedTohack"].Value = "True";
                    Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
                    Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = null;
                    throw new HttpException("Invalid:"+newSessionID);



                }

                //Use the default one so application will work as usual//ASP.NET_SessionId
                Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value.Substring(0, 24);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {

            if (Ex.Message == "Invalid")
            {                  
                 Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/PraiseError.aspx?Message={0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(Ex.Message)));
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
  protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string gn = GenerateHashKey();
        try
        {
            //Pass the custom Session ID to the browser.
            if (Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
            {



                Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value.Replace(gn, "") + gn;

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value + gn;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value + gn;
        }
    }

private string GenerateHashKey()
{
        StringBuilder myStr = new StringBuilder();
        myStr.Append(Request.Browser.Browser);
        myStr.Append(Request.Browser.Platform);
        myStr.Append(Request.Browser.MajorVersion);
        myStr.Append(Request.Browser.MinorVersion);
        myStr.Append(Request.UserHostAddress);
       //myStr.Append(Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.Value);
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hashdata = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myStr.ToString()));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashdata);

 }
```

Comment: You could opt to not bother at all, because this does not add any security at all. The hash is generated from the user agent string, which is provided by the client. A malicious client who can capture someone else's cookies, can capture their user agent string as well... It's a very typical CodeProject article, to say the least. The only added value is in the IP address check, which could be done in plenty other ways.

Comment: is there any alternative to this then?

Comment: Would it not be safe to say, that the StrBuilder in the GenerateHash function actually allows you to come up with any combination of required input allowing a pretty dynamic and unique string to be built and then hashed. And thus allowing for a strong security password ?